# What's the term for adding something to a project so that a manager can remove it to feel like they've contributed?

Tags: management

I first heard of this from a blog post or twitter thread from someone in game development, but can't remember the term they used for it. Basically the idea is: you're designing a level or whatever, and you know that your manager will never just say "yep that's perfect, ship it", they will always want to make their mark on it by going "that's good, but what if you added/removed x?". So from the start you put something in that you know they won't like, but you won't have to feel defensive about cutting it.

What's the term for this? Is there actually a widely-known one or is it only used by the person I'm thinking of?

Comment: Call it "decoy"?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on another form, but not meta (my only supplied choice).

Comment: "Sacrificial lamb", "decoy", "distraction"

Comment: This probably would have gotten more and better alternatives over at https://english.stackexchange.com/ but it looks like OP got the answer they were looking for. Not sure if asking for workplace terms is actually off topic here though, [this meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/can-we-add-a-new-close-reason/2246#2246) implies it is OK though it's old and didn't get many votes. @MichaelMcFarlane

Comment: It’s called padding, used to do it to my manager when we needed consumables: add a few extra and he had something to remove - allowed him to feel in control of his budget…

Comment: I have a feeling that this post must be protected already.

Comment: also relevant: [The secret of a successful code review](https://www.commitstrip.com/en/2021/04/09/the-secret-of-a-successful-code-review/) (from commitstrip.com)

Comment: everyone who has been in the military understands this - with some inspecting officers, never have a perfect uniform, they will find something like make you buy new shoes.  Give them something like a loose thread they can find and is super easy to fix for the re-inspection.

Comment: Kind of surprised that people think a question about a specific term relating to management is off-topic when half the popular questions on this site are "how do I deal with my very specific, non-generalisable situation" which is basically antithetical to the SE model, but oh well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may be thinking of [this story from the development of Battle Chess](https://rachelbythebay.com/w/2013/06/05/duck/), with "the duck".

Comment: Ah yep, that's the one

Comment: Read the story. Just walked my dog this morning, and she has to mark everything. Apparently there are managers like my dog.

Answer (score 12):

A duck
https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/
scroll down to point 5
but it is not commonly known jargon

Answer (score 0):

I think I've heard something similar with regards to an allegory about **painting sheds**. You bring up something trivial, like the color of a shed, in a meeting with the sole intent of having the idea shot down or revised instead of some other more important issue.

I don't remember where I read about it but I found this article that mentions something similar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality

Comment: This has nothing to do with the subject of _adding_ something on purpose though.

Answer (score -6):

Leaving someone some fish.  An adaptation from the expression that if you feed a man a fish he eats for the day. If you teach him how to fish he can feed his family for life.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be “feeding someone a fish”, then? Who just leaves a fish lying around?

Comment: To leave a red herring is a way to get dogs off of your trail.